# Performant way to convert Json to Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart) with Data coming from back end.

I have to convert the JSON data which I retrieve from the server.

The following function is working fine and giving what I wish,

but I'm asking if there is more performant way (*without loop ?*) to convert data from Json to Array.

**Input Json Data**

> [{    "W": 1,     "rec": 0,   "tr": 0,    "Open": 24 }, {     "W": 2,     "rec": 43,
> "tr": 40,   "Open": 27 }, {     "W": 3,     "rec": 26,  "tr": 34,   "Open":
> 19 }, {   "W": 4,     "rec": 53,  "tr": 50,   "Open": 22 }, {     "W": 5,
> "rec": 53,  "tr": 56,   "Open": 19 }, {     "W": 6,     "rec": 40,  "tr":
> 34,   "Open": 25 }, {     "W": 7,     "rec": 37,  "tr": 38,   "Open": 24 }, {
> "W": 8,     "rec": 45,  "tr": 44,   "Open": 25 }]

**Output Array Data**

> [["W","rec","tr","Open"], [1,0,0,24], [2,43,40,27], [3,26,34,19],
> [4,53,50,22], [5,53,56,19], [6,40,34,25], [7,37,38,24], [8,40,42,22]]

```
function JsontoTable(obj) {        
    var myarray = [];
    var keys = [];
    for (var k in obj[0]) keys.push(k);
    myarray.push(keys);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var k in obj[i]) { arr.push(obj[i][k]); }
        myarray.push(arr);
    }
    return (myarray);}
```

Comment: This is just converting from an array to another different array.  Perhaps the data was JSON at some point, but there is no sign of JSON here.

Comment: You can use `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` and `Array#map()` but it's still going to iterate through all items. There is no magical way to visit all items of an array without visiting all items of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let inputArray = [{ "W": 1, "rec": 0, "tr": 0, "Open": 24 }, { "W": 2, "rec": 43, "tr": 40, "Open": 27 }, { "W": 3, "rec": 26, "tr": 34, "Open": 19 }, { "W": 4, "rec": 53, "tr": 50, "Open": 22 }, { "W": 5, "rec": 53, "tr": 56, "Open": 19 }, { "W": 6, "rec": 40, "tr": 34, "Open": 25 }, { "W": 7, "rec": 37, "tr": 38, "Open": 24 }, { "W": 8, "rec": 45, "tr": 44, "Open": 25 }];

const outputArray = [Object.keys(inputArray[0])].concat(inputArray.map(Object.values));

console.log(outputArray);
```

Comment: Its possible to generate output array in on loop `O(n)` james; current solution will be `O(2n)`

Comment: @Mhmdrz_A not sure I agree - there is only one "loop" here, inputArray.map.  Feel free to explain further or post another answer.

Comment: `Object.keys` and `Object.values` are two separate loops over the object. btw they are necessary complexities as I see now. yeah it's fine.